# Basic python multi-threading issue

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

New to python and trying to understand multi-threading. Here's an example from python documentation on [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#module-Queue)

For the heck of my life, I don't understand how this example is working. In the worker() function, there's an infinite loop. How does the worker know when to get out of the loop? There seems to be no breaking condition.

And what exactly is the join doing at the end? Shouldn't I be joining the threads instead?

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

Also another question, When should multithreading be used and when should multiprocessing be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup. You're right. `worker` will run forever. However since Queue only has a finite number of items, eventually `worker` will permanently block at `q.get()` (Since there will be no more items in the queue). At this point, it's inconsequential that `worker` is still running. `q.join()` blocks until the Queue count drops to 0 (whenever the worker thread calls `q.task_done`, the count drops by 1). After that, the program ends. And the infinitely blocking thread dies with it's creator.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Is there any website/resources where I could read up on such subtleties? The documentation really is not the best place it seems.

Comment: Apart from the point that the end of the main thread kills the child threads, all of that information comes straight out of the `Queue` documentation page that you linked yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I will accept it as it answers my major question.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding your second question, the biggest difference between threads and processes in Python is that the mainstream implementations use a global interpreter lock (GIL) to ensure that multiple threads can't mess up Python's internal data structures. This means that for programs that spend most of their time doing computation in pure Python, even with multiple CPUs you're not going to speed the program up much because only one thread at a time can hold the GIL. On the other hand, multiple threads can trivially share data in a Python program, and in some (but by no means all) cases, you don't have to worry too much about thread safety.

Where multithreading can speed up a Python program is when the program spends most of its time waiting on I/O -- disk access or, particularly these days, network operations. The GIL is not held while doing I/O, so many Python threads can run concurrently in I/O bound applications.

On the other hand, with multiprocessing, each process has its own GIL, so your performance can scale to the number of CPU cores you have available. The down side is that all communication between the processes will have to be done through a multiprocessing.Queue (which acts on the surface very like a Queue.Queue, but has very different underlying mechanics, since it has to communicate across process boundaries).

Since working through a thread safe or interprocess queue avoids a lot of potential threading problems, and since Python makes it so easy, the `multiprocessing` module is very attractive.

Comment: Great answer, it's a shame I can't up-vote since I just signed up. I am doing multi-threading/processing since I need to read in multiple data files (thousands of them) in parallel, read some information from them, and then write back to files on to the disk (again in thousands). So should I be using multi-threading or multi-processing? Seems like I will be doing fair amount of I/O.

Comment: And also it is not clear to me, how to "join" the processes. I have a loop at the end that loops through each of the processes created, and calls join, but still my code does not terminate.

Comment: If the master thread calls `childThread.join()`, the child thread has to terminate on its own, which the example code above doesn't do. Your example code uses the `Queue.join()`, which is very different. It might be time to take the code you currently have and put up a new question.

Comment: Multithreading versus multiprocessing is a tough judgement call, but fortunately it's pretty easy to switch due to the similarities in the APIs. If the files are big and you're not doing much computation on them, multithreading will be fine. If you're doing a lot of computation relative to a small amount of data read and written, multiprocessing might be a bigger win.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does answer my question but since my major question was dealing with explanation for the code snippet, I will accept Joel's answer.

Comment: Agree. Multiprocessing can indeed speed up some io intensive programs but Multithreading will do just fine when you are waiting for web traffic and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with joel-cornett, **mostly**. I tried to run the following snippet in python2.7 :

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue

def worker():
    def do_work(item):
        print(item)

    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(4):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in range(10):
    q.put(item)

q.join()
```

The output is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Exception in thread Thread-3 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
  File "abc.py", line 9, in worker
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 236, in wait
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

*Most probable explanation i think:*

As the queue gets empty after task exhaustion, parent thread quits, after returning from q.join() and destroys the queue. Child threads are terminated upon receiving the first TypeError exception produced in "item = q.get()", as the queue exists no more.

Comment: I'm not getting the same result as you _even_ if I remove `q.join()` and ensure that the parent thread dies before processing is done.