# Basic issues with Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I can't figure out what's wrong with the following python multiprocessing code. It does not terminate. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock

def hello(num, myqueue):
   while True:
      item = myqueue.get()
      print 'Thread ', num, 'got', item
   return

def put_on_queue(myqueue):
   for i in range(10):
      myqueue.put(i)
   return

if __name__ == '__main__':
   processes = []

   myqueue = Queue()

   for i in range(4):
      proc = Process(target = hello, args = (i, myqueue))
      proc.start()
      processes.append(proc)

   put_on_queue(myqueue)

   for proc in processes:
       proc.join()
```

-------------- EDIT -----------------

OK, so based on the comments I received, and some online help I revised my code as below. Still no luck :-(

```
def hello(num, myqueue):
  while not exit_flag:
     item = myqueue.get(False,5)
     print 'Thread ', num, 'got', item
  return


def put_on_queue(myqueue):
  global exit_flag 
  for i in range(10):         
     myqueue.put(i)

   while not myqueue.empty():
      pass
   exit_flag = 1

   return

if __name__ == '__main__':
  mylock = Lock()
  processes = []
  myqueue = Queue()

  exit_flag = 0

  for i in range(4):
     proc = Process(target = hello, args = (i, myqueue))
     #proc.daemon = True
     proc.start()
     processes.append(proc)

  put_on_queue(myqueue)

  for proc in processes:
     proc.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an infinite loop inside your `hello` function.
You have to put a sentinent as a last value into the queue, check for it and break out of the loop.

Comment: You are right... even if `queue.get` was not blocking it would be stuck with the loop.

Comment: Once you join all the processes, the child process does terminate automatically regardless of whether it's in an infinite loop or not. I think. See the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620431/basic-python-multi-threading-issue) I posted yesterday.

Comment: @JayZee: I think you misunderstood that other answer. Form the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) of `.join()`: *"Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs."* So the calling process can only terminate when the child processes terminate. But they never do! Note that in your other question, the **queue** is joined, not the other threads.

Comment: @Jay: As I already said, `.join()` makes the calling process **wait** until the **child process terminates**. But your child process contains an **infinite loop**, it will never terminate and hence won't the calling process. I don't know how I can explain it better. **But** even if you didn't have an infinite loop, `queue.get()` is **blocking**, so you have to take care of that as well (make it non-blocking or use a sentinel value).

Comment: @FelixKling : I made some changes (please see updated question), and still not working :-(